# Enable Email in Docusign Dev account?

Tags: docusignapi

We are using Drawloop to generate documents within a Salesforce Sandbox and are sending those documents into a DocuSign Dev account. The document is being generated and is being sent into DocuSign without an issue. The problem is that notification emails to signers are not being sent from Docusign. When in Docusign the 'Remind' button is also not sending any emails to signers. Is there a way to enable email in this Dev DocuSign account?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Thanks for chimiing in. This ended up not being a DocuSign config issue, but was an issue with the Integration configuration

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a configuration issue of your integration.

Standard demo accounts send out email just fine. Try it by sending a signing request from the web interface (vs sending via Drawloop and Salesforce).

You can also send via the API by using either the [API Explorer](http://apiexplorer.docusign.com) or the [Recipe framework](https://github.com/docusign/esignature-recipes-python) (run it on Heroku for free).